# Extract Part of a text file in BAT

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am capturing a m3U file on a daily basis but wish to parse part of it to another file with the few channels I need.

For example I have renamed my m3U to Test.txt file which say has the following fictional structure:

> ```
> #EXTINF:0,ABC  
> #live link 1
> #EXTINF:0,XYZ   
> #live link 2
> #EXTINF:0,UVW  
> #live link 3
> ```

I would just like to capture say the line staring from "#EXTINF:0,XYZ" and  say the line beneath it to end up with a Output.txt as follows:

> ```
> #EXTINF:0,XYZ   
> #live link 2
> ```

I know that one needs to use the For loop but I am a bit of a noob on this area.

Comment: Yes it could have white spaces.

Comment: Is it possible that the part `XYZ` contains white-spaces? can there be trailing white-spaces as in your sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this, supposing the `.m3u` file does not contain trailing white-spaces in the lines preceded by `#EXTINF`, like your sample data does:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~1"
set "HEADER=#EXTM3U"
set "PREFIX=#EXTINF"
set "MATCH=%~2"

set "FLAG="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%FILE%") do (
    if defined FLAG (
        echo(%%L
        set "FLAG="
    )
    for /F "delims=:" %%P in ("%%L") do (
        if "%%P"=="%HEADER%" (
            echo(%%L
        ) else if "%%P"=="%PREFIX%" (
            set "LINE=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if /I "!LINE:*,=!"=="!MATCH!" (
                echo(!LINE!
                endlocal
                set "FLAG=#"
            ) else endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Call the script like this, supposing it is saved as `extract-entry.bat`:

```
extract-entry.bat "input_file.m3u" "XYZ" > "output_file.m3u"
```

The script walks through the given `.m3u` file line by line. It returns the current line unedited and resets variable `FLAG`, if variable `FLAG` is set, which is not the case at the beginning.

Then it looks for `#EXTINF`. If found (e. g., `#EXTINF:0,XYZ`), the string after the comma (`XYZ`) is compared against the given search string. If matched, the current line is output and `FLAG` variable is set now in order to get the following line too.

The header line `#EXTM3U` is always output.

Toggling [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) makes this script robust against all characters that have special meaning to the command interpreter without losing them.

Comment: Thanks - This seems to be working fine for one line. However I would like to include this command in another bat file and extract more than 1 channel to various files ... The bat file is just finishing off after the first channel I extracted.

Comment: What do you mean by *more than 1 channel*? do you mean to extract more than one `#EXTINF:` section, or do you mean more than one line after a single `#EXTINF:` section?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself well ... I managed to get over this by using CALL in front of extract-entry.bat. I all worked well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I see, you call this from another script; yes, you need to use `call`, because otherwise, execution won't return to the caller script...

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into the file filter.cmd.

```
@echo off
set INPUT=%1&set MATCH=%2& set MATCHED=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%INPUT%) do call :line "%%~a"
goto :eof
:line
set EXT=&TITLE=&
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ("%~1") do set EXT=%%~a
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:," %%a in ("%~1") do set TITLE=%%~c
if "%EXT%" == "#EXTM3U" echo %~1
if "%EXT%" == "#EXTINF" (
  set MATCHED=0
  echo %TITLE%| findstr /l %MATCH% >nul  && set MATCHED=1
)
if %MATCHED%==1 echo %~1
```

Use example:

```
filter.cmd input_file.m3u XYZ > output_file.m3u
```

Here is some explanation:
Every input line is split using for /f with tokens and delims.
MATCHED is set if the line begins with #EXTINF and the rest contains the string to match (second argument).
if MATCHED is set, the lines are output until next #EXTINF.

Comment: 1. It is not quite efficient to parse every line twice by `for /F`, you could easily combine them. 2. You should replace `%1` by `%~1`, same for `%2`. 3. The syntax `set "VAR=Value"` is more secure against special characters (e. g., what if a string contains `&`?). 4. You should put `%MATCH%` in between `""` in the `findstr` command line. 5. I recommend to provide switch `/X` to `findstr` in order for the whole title to match and/or the `/C` switch to define a literal search string (note that without `/C`, white-spaces in the search string constitute word separators).

Comment: 1. I didn't try to show a bulletproof and minimal solution, if I did, I would have done it in another language anyway.
The point was to illustrate the use of for loops.                  
2-4. There is no need to replace %1 to %~1, quote set =, MATCH, INPUT, because they come from the command line already properly quoted.
And if someone runs the script with unquoted parameters containing &, you can do nothing about it.

Comment: Proper quoting is *very* important in batch: using `%~1` removes quotes, stating `"%~1"` in the code ensures proper quoting; `%1` is expanded to the argument as is, `%~1` removes surrounding quotes, so `"%~1"` is the most secure way to have quoted strings (`"%1"` could even lead to over-quoted strings if already provided in a quoted way); quotes avoid trouble with white-spaces (token separators) and special characters occurring in the strings; nevertheless, your answer does illustrate how `for /F` works...

Comment: These are well known facts, and I must emphasize again, that there is no need to replace %1 when:
1. %1 starts and ends with a quote, in that case it is equivalend to "%~1"
2. %1 does not contain special characters, in that case it is safe to use it as is.
Of course, replacing %1 with just %~1  would be wrong, as well as replacing %1 with "%1".

Comment: Using `"%~1"` is the most secure way, that's all I wanted to say; there is no ultimate all-encompassing way though (think of arguments like `"&"&` for instance), but with the restriction that there are *no quotes inside* an argument, `"%~1"` is safe...